# Linux default value in a for loop if not specified in command line

Tags: linux, bash

How would I write a Linux script to print numbers 1 through n, one on each line. **But if n isn't specified, a default value of 10 will be used.**

Example: 
script name is value

./value 20 should print 1 through 20 on each line

./value should print 1 through 10 on each line by default

My Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

num=$1
for (( i = 1 ; i <= ${num} ; i++ ))
do   
  echo $i
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put in the rest of [the substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html).

```
${num:-10}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

num=${1:-10}

for (( i = 1 ; i <= ${num} ; i++ ))

do

echo $i

done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply catch an empty argument and replace it, with something like:

```
num=$1
[[ -z "$num" ]] && num=10
```

The advantage to this method is that you can apply *arbitrary* checks to the argument to ensure it's valid, *not* just catching an empty argument:

```
deflt=10
[[ -z "$num" ]]        && echo 'No argument'     && num=$deflt
[[ $num =~ -.* ]]      && echo 'Starts with "-"' && num=$deflt
[[ ! $num =~ [0-9]+ ]] && echo 'Not integer'     && num=$deflt
[[ $num -gt 99 ]]      && echo 'Too big'         && num=$deflt
```